# Idiomatic way to print arbitrary number of items from a list on each line

Tags: python

I want to print data from a list, such as:

```
['0.10', '0.15', '-0.25', '0.30', '1.50', '1.70']
```

However, rather than printing one element in the list using something like:

```
for item in list:
    print item
```

I want to print an arbitrary number of items from the list on each line.  I can think of many messy ways to do it and I saw an answer which used the grouper recipe from the itertools page on the docs.  I'm happy to use that, but I suspect there might be a better way of doing it.

An example output I might like would be:

```
0.10   0.15  -0.25
0.30   1.50   1.70
```

Or:

```
0.10   0.15  -0.25   0.30
1.50   1.70
```

So the number of items on each line isn't necessarily a factor of the number of items on the list.  Some lines may end with fewer elements if the list is too short.

Comment: What's wrong with the grouper recipe?  It's probably the best you can get.

Comment: I didn't think there was anything wrong with it, I just don't have a very good feel for Python idioms and was wondering if someone knew of a quick way.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about the grouper receipe (and a few others) is that it's a recipe, not a function. On what planet is copy-and-paste better than import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works.  It seems pretty simple.

```
for i in range(0, len(some_list), line_length):
    print( some_list[i:i+line_length] )
```

If you want the literal formatting shown in the question, you'd have to do something like this.

```
for i in range(0, len(some_list), line_length):
    print( "  ".join( "{0:.2f}".format(x) for x in some_list[i:i+line_length] ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another still (maybe) simpler version:

```
mylist = ['0.10', '0.15', '-0.25', '0.30', '1.50', '1.70']
line_items = 3

for n, item in enumerate(mylist):
    if (n+1) % line_items:
        print item,
    else:
        print item
```

produces:

```
0.10 0.15 -0.25
0.30 1.50 1.70
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this solution is a little bit more clear:

```
a = ['0.10', '0.15', '-0.25', '0.30', '1.50', '1.70']
body = []
length = 2
for b in xrange(len(a)):
    body.append(str(a[b]))
    if b % length:
        body.append("\n")
    else:
        body.append("\t")
print "".join(body)
```

Hope this one helps :)

PS: And actually a one print only solution might be helpful in lists containing many variables.